# How do I animate a camera with the Three.js animation system?

Tags: animation, three.js, camera

I'm trying to animate a perspective camera using `AnimationAction` but nothing happens when I call `myAction.play()`.

```
const positionKF = new THREE.VectorKeyframeTrack( '.position', [ 0, 1, 2 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 50, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ] );
const clip = new THREE.AnimationClip( 'Action', 5, [ positionKF ] );

// create new AnimationMixer
const myMixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer( camera2 );
// create new ClipAction and make it play
const clipAction = myMixer.clipAction( clip );
clipAction.play();
```

And nothing happens. Am I doing something wrong here? Or are camera's impossible to animate this way?

Comment: Are you updating `myMixer` in your animation loop?

Comment: @Mugen87 No. Does AnimationMixer need to be updated even after calling play()?

Comment: I've added an answer to your question with the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to update the instance of `AnimationMixer` per frame. A typical animation loop looks like so:

```
function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    const delta = clock.getDelta(); // clock is an instance of THREE.Clock

    if ( mixer ) mixer.update( delta );

    renderer.render( scene, camera );

}
```

`three.js R106`